# Tk window will not close after window.quit() and crashes program

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, apple-m1

**The issue**
When creating a Tk window to generate a CheckboxTreeview widget for file selection, the user will select files for further analysis and click a button "Select files" which quits the window and returns the selection for further processing.

The issue is that when the user selects the "Select files" button and the program continues, but the Tk window will remain with the rainbow wheel and eventually crash my program throwing the error:

> Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread

This seems to be predominately related to issues with Tk and M1 processors on Mac.

**My code**

```
def selectFiles(DictionaryOfFiles):
  from ttkwidgets import CheckboxTreeview
  import tkinter as tk
  from tkinter import ttk

  window = tk.Tk()

  tree = CheckboxTreeview(window)
  tree.pack()
  window.title('Select files for analysis')
  window.geometry('400x400')

  # iterate through dictionary of folders and files and create a
  # checkbox tree - all files checked by default    
  key_lst = list(DictionaryOfFiles.keys())  
  val_lst = list(DictionaryOfFiles.values())
  for n in key_lst: 
      tree.insert("","end",n,text=n)
      tree.insert(n,"end",DictionaryOfFiles[n],text=DictionaryOfFiles[n])
      tree.change_state(n,"checked")
      tree.change_state(DictionaryOfFiles[n],"checked")

  exit_button = ttk.Button(window,text="Select files",command=window.quit)
  exit_button.pack(pady=20)
  window.mainloop() 

  selection = tree.get_checked()
  window.destroy()

  selection_dict = {}
  for n in selection:
      position = val_lst.index([n])
      selection_dict[key_lst[position]] = n

  return selection_dict
```

The function selectFiles() is called from another script `myprogram.py` which passes it 'DictionaryOfFiles' which consists of subfolder keys and filename values.

**What I am using**
I am running a MacBook Pro with an M1 Pro with Ventura 13.4. Program is being run with Visual Studio Code.

I have also run this on an Ubuntu 22.04 machine with the same Tcl:AsyncDelete error.

**What I have tried**
I have looked around at a few solutions, including installing Python 3.9.1 and Tkinter 8.6.1 from [this issue](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/5363#issue-1203892496). This resolved the commonly encountered 'blank Tk window' that gets generated after `window = tk.Tk()` is called.

Changing `command=window.quit` to `comand=window.destroy` succesfully closes the window, but the `mainloop` does not stop and the program gets stuck.

Running from the mac terminal `python myprogram.py` results in the same error.

Finally, it seems like `wait_window` is what I am after but I cannot figure out how to implement it.

**Other notes**
I am open to other ideas for checkbox trees, it does not have to be from Tk. I am doing the bulk of my development on this Mac so I would ideally like a solution, particularly if I am going to be deploying software to users that have Apple silicon machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this after some deeper research, see below for details.

For starters, I had accidentally left a `root = Tk()` window undestroyed in the `myprogram.py` script. Destroying it meant that I did not have to revert my python or Tk version to a earlier one as it removed the empty Tk window that would show up.

Next, the `command=window.quit` function was not appropriate. It needed to include a `lambda` function instead, so the updated code was:

```
  def destroy():
    global selection
    selection = tree.get_checked()
    window.destroy()
 exit_button = ttk.Button(window,text="Select files",command=lambda:destroy())
```

By using calling a `def` function for `command` I could also get it to output the selected checkboxes to `selection` by using `global`. The `lambda` function also prevented the `Button` from automatically running `destroy()` so that it only destroyed the window and returned `selection` when the button was actually pressed.

However, from this another issue arose - the `window` *window* would hang after `window.destroy()` was called. The program would now run fine without error, but the window hanging was annoying. To resolve this, I called `window.update()` after `window.destroy()` and it completely resolved the issue.

The final code is now:

```
def selectFiles(DictionaryOfFiles):
   from ttkwidgets import CheckboxTreeview
   import tkinter as tk
   from tkinter import ttk

  def destroy():
     global selection
     selection = tree.get_checked()
     window.destroy()
     window.update()

  window = tk.Tk()

  tree = CheckboxTreeview(window)
  tree.pack()
  window.title('Select files for analysis')
  window.geometry('400x400')

  # iterate through dictionary of folders and files and create a
  # checkbox tree - all files checked by default    
  key_lst = list(DictionaryOfFiles.keys())  
  val_lst = list(DictionaryOfFiles.values())
  for n in key_lst: 
      tree.insert("","end",n,text=n)
      tree.insert(n,"end",DictionaryOfFiles[n],text=DictionaryOfFiles[n])
      tree.change_state(n,"checked")
      tree.change_state(DictionaryOfFiles[n],"checked")  

  exit_button = ttk.Button(window,text="Select   files",command=lambda:destroy())
  exit_button.pack(pady=20)

  window.mainloop() 

  selection_dict = {}
  for n in selection:
      position = val_lst.index([n])
      selection_dict[key_lst[position]] = n

  return selection_dict
      window.update()
```